# Anet A8 frame replacement

Tags: diy-3d-printer, anet-a8, hardware

My Anet A8 frame are broken. I find frame project [AM8 - Metal Frame for Anet A8](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2263216). I like it but I can't find aluminum extrusion needed, like this: [MiSUMi - Aluminum Extrusion - 5 series, Base 20, 20mm x 40mm](https://us.misumi-ec.com/vona2/detail/110302684350/?Inch=0&CategorySpec=00000042730%3A%3A20x40).

Maybe somebody knows where I can buy it in Ukraine? Or maybe another frame options?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an English based Q&A site.

Comment: I can understand that this is an English language site, but is it limited by charter to only English based resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of online sources for T-slot aluminum extrusions from [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/) to [McMaster](https://www.mcmaster.com/#t-slotted-framing/=18c9twv).  If you want more options do a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=t-slot%20aluminum%20extrusion&rlz=1C1GNAM_enUS688US688&oq=t-slot%20a&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.6487j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend the Bosch Rexroth series of aluminum hardware.

I also recommend RS components as a distributor for this material. They have local warehouses, and provide very fast shipping.

[Here](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/tubing-struts/4667219/) is the part you are looking for on their UK GB website.
[Here](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/?sra=oss&r=t&searchTerm=bosch%20rexroth) is an assortment of compatible hardware.

By the way, RS components has a Ukraine website, where you may be able to order from a Ukraine warehouse for faster/cheaper shipping.

Answer (score 1):

Not precisely cheap, but if you look on aliExpress for *AM8 3D Printer Extrusion Metal Frame* you will find kits build precisely for moving Anet A8 to aluminium frame